# Probability of one coin toss sequence before the other

Tags: probability

I have found an answer to this question but am not completely confident in it. The question states:

A game involves four players $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$. Each player selects a sequence of heads and tails before a coin is tossed until one of the selected sequences occurs. The player whose sequence is the first to appear wins. Suppose $P_1$ selects the sequence HHT, $P_2$ the sequence THH, $P_3$ the sequence TTH and $P_5$ the sequence HTT.

1. If only $P_1$ and $P_2$ play, determine the probability that $P_1$ wins.
2. If all four players play, determine the probability of each one winning.

I found the approach to both parts to be the same. For part 1. I defined the sample space $$\Omega_2=\{(a,b,c,d,e,f):a,b,c,d,e,f\in\{H,T\}\}$$. Then $|\Omega_2|=2^6$. The event that player $P_1$ wins is $A$. It has $1\cdot2^3$ scenarios, hence $P(A)=\frac{2^3}{2^6}=\frac1{2^3}$.

For part 2. I applied the same logic. $|\Omega_4|=2^{12}$ with the event that a player wins, $|A|=1\cdot2^3\cdot2^3\cdot2^3=2^9$, hence $P(A)=\frac{2^9}{2^{12}}=\frac1{2^3}$.

My main concern lies in the fact that both probabilities are the same as well as my approach to how I structured the sample space.

Comment: I think there's a problem here, but I want to be sure: why is your sample space 6 coins? How are you using that sample space? What happens if the first six coins flipped are all heads (meaning the game is not yet resolved)?

Comment: Look up  Penney's game

Answer (score 1):

### First question

If the first two results are H, then P1 wins. Indeed, in this case, as long as H is observed, the final 3 results would be HHH and another flip is necessary. As soon as there is a T, the last three results are HHT, P1 wins. P2 cannot win.

If the first two results are not H (TT, HT, TH), then P2 wins. As soon as there is two H in a row, the last three results are THH and then P2 wins. P1 cannot win because there will never be another flip after two H in a row.

Noting $F_1$ the first flip and $F_2$ the second flip, we have (assuming $F_i$ follows a Bernoulli distribution of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$):
$$P(A)=P(F_1=H,F_2=H)=\frac{1}{4}$$
and then:
$$P(A^C)=\frac{3}{4}$$

### Second question

If the first two results are H, like previously P1 wins. Indeed, in this case, as long as H is observed, the final 3 results would be HHH and another flip is necessary. As soon as there is a T, the last three results are HHT, P1 wins. Nobody else can win.
$$P(P1 wins) \geq \frac{1}{4}$$

If the first two results are T, like previously P3 wins. Indeed, in this case, as long as T is observed, the final 3 results would be TTT and another flip is necessary. As soon as there is a H, the last three results are TTH, P3 wins. Nobody else can win.
$$P(P3 wins) \geq \frac{1}{4}$$

Otherwise, the first two results are different: HT or TH. As soon as there are 2 identical results in a row, this is over. If the last 2 results are H, it means the final sequence is THH, then P2 wins. It they are T, the final sequence is HTT, P4 wins. Otherwise, the last sequence is either THT or HTH and then another flip is required. P1 and P3 cannot win.
$$P(P1 wins | F_1=H, F_2=T) = 0$$
$$P(P1 wins | F_1=T, F_2=H) = 0$$
$$P(P3 wins | F_1=H, F_2=T) = 0$$
$$P(P3 wins | F_1=T, F_2=H) = 0$$
And then
$$P(P1 wins) = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$P(P3 wins) = \frac{1}{4}$$

When the first two flips are different, because of the symmetry I would say that P2 wins in half cases and P4 and the other half. Then, finally:
$$P(P2 wins) = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$P(P4 wins) = \frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 possible sequences for the first three tosses. How can player P2 win? The first three tosses THH is one way, otherwise there must be some other sequence that precedes THH. It could be HHT, but P1 wins, game over, on that sequence. It has to be HHH. When sequence HHH appears it can last indefinitely but must change to THH eventually. That's it for the 2 player game. P1 wins most of the time: all the sequences for the first 3 tosses beside HHT and HHH are P1 wins.